# Product of standard and sign representation of $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters, young-tableaux

I am able to work out the [sign representation](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group:S5) of $S_5$ and [standard representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558228/standard-representation-of-s-5) of $S_5$.

How do I compute the product of standard and sign representation of $S_5$?

What kind of product do I need to take? For any given group element in $S_5$, do I just need to multiply the sign representation (which is a scalar value of 1 or -1) with the standard representation (which is a $4 \times 4$ matrix)?

My effort:
The answer here [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745262/why-does-the-tensor-product-of-an-irreducible-representation-with-the-sign-repre) suggests to take the tensor product which will increase the dimension of the vector space. But I already know that the dimensions of the product of standard and sign representation of $S_5$ and the standard representation are $4$.

Comment: Why do you say it will increase the dimension? The dimension of a tensor product is the product of the dimensions, so here the dimension will be $1 \cdot 4 = 4$. In terms of matrices, the tensor product corresponds to the Kronecker product. (The Kronecker product with a $1 \times 1$ matrix is just scalar multiplication.)

Comment: @A.P., you are right. I was incorrect.